# Large family of subsets with small pairwise intersections

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, graph-reconstruction

(Crossposting from StackExchange 4799692 after it has been there for a while.)

Let $\alpha>0$ be a constant (can be sufficiently small if necessary) and $n$ be sufficiently large. What can we say about the cardinality of a family of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, each of size $k$, such that any two of the subsets intersect in at most $\alpha k$ elements, when $k$ is of size linear in $n$?

I was able to find relevant results only when $k = O(\sqrt{n})$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3666339/347678) and when $k$ is fixed ("On a Packing and Covering Problem", Rodl, 1985).

Any idea if results for other ranges of $k$ are available? I am more interested in constructions rather than upper bounds, since the context in Rodl's work anyway gives $\binom{n}{\alpha k}/\binom{k}{\alpha k}$ as a reasonable upper bound.

Any help appreciated!